# How to use the multiple parameter in postman

Tags: spring-boot, variables, parameters, postman

I just want to know that how we can pass multiple variable or parameter in the message body by using the Spring boot.

Want to pass more than two variable in the postman as a parameter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot not support multipe requestbody.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but there are many ways to pass parameters to an API.

**As a JSON object**

If you just want to pass multiple parameters you'd just pass them in json format in the request body as a post or a put:

```json
{
  "firstName": "bob",
  "lastName": "smith",
  "middleName": "joe"
}
```

And your controller method would look something like

```java
public Name createName(
    @RequestBody Name name
) {}
```

**As a JSON list**

If you mean you have multiple values for the same parameter then you can pass them as a list.

```json
[ 
  {"firstName": "bob"},
  {"firstName": "joe"},
  {"firstName": "jerry"}
]
```

And your controller method would look something like

```java
public List<Name> nameList createName(
    @RequestBody List<Name> nameList
) {}
```

or

```json
{
  "firstNames": [ 
    {"firstName": "bob"},
    {"firstName": "joe"},
    {"firstName": "jerry"}
  ]
}
```

And your controller method would look something like

```java
public Names createName(
    @RequestBody Names names
) {}
```

In this example Names would be an object that contains a variable

```java
List<Name> nameList;
```

**In the uri**

Another option to pass values to the api is to include them a path parameters
from postman your uri would look something like this:

using @RequestParam on the API

http://localhost:8080/apiPath?firstName=bob&lastName=smith&middleName=joe

or

using @PathVariable on the API

http://localhost:8080/apiPath/firstName/bob/lastName/smith/middleName/joe